# Javascript get Div info from nested Div

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a google chrome extension that gets the countdown timer amount from a div, from an online gaming sites, auctions site, etc. After I get the amount I can post different calculations of the time in a div I inject into the html.

My div injection works great. Getting the time is the problem.

The current site I am getting the countdown info from is a gaming site. I have located the div that contains the countdown info and the div id name, but the actual countdown info is in a nested div that does not have an id.

the structure of the divs is as follows:

```
<div id="countdowndiv">
   <div class="info">
       <div class="time">
           1m 39s
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

There are multiple divs with the class of "time" and "info", so I don't think I can use document.getElementsByClassName().

Is there anyway to get this countdown amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways, one you can just traverse along the dom:

```
document.getElementById('countdowndiv').children[0].children[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.querySelectorAll('div#countdowndiv div#time')` but you should note that it isn't completely cross-browswer compatible. More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you don't have to worry about cross-browser issues (as the only target browser is Chrome), you can safely use [**document.querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to get specific element with a single selector expression, combining the power of `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementById`. For example:

```
var countDownNode = document.querySelector('#countdowndiv .time'),
    countDown     = countDownNode && countDownNode.innerHTML;
```

Still, if the structure is exactly like you've shown in the question, there's an easier way:

```
var countDown = document.getElementById('countdowndiv').textContent;
```

... as `textContent` property, quoting [**the doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent), '.*..returns the concatenation of the textContent attribute value of every child node, excluding comments and processing instruction nodes*'. You may use `trim` on it before giving to the main parsing block, or just leave it as is.

Comment: In fact, unless one has to support IE7- explicitly, QS/QSA are [safe to use](http://caniuse.com/queryselector).